# An array of arrays of different sizes

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I'm learning R and I'd like to make an "array of arrays" (not sure if the expression is correct) inserting for example these values

```
N_seq = c(10,50,100,500,1000)
```

inside this function (not correct):

```
x = rnorm(N_seq,3.2,1)
```

The desired result should be like an object made by five arrays (as `length(N_seq) = 5`) where each one is equal to the result of `x` inserting each value of `N_seq` (so that `x[1]` has the values of `rnorm(N_seq[i], 3.2, 1)` with length 10, and `x[2]` has the values `rnorm(N_seq[2], 3.2, 1)` with length 50, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ragged array, use ["list"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists). This is a special type of "vector" in R. You can not only hold vectors of difference length in each list element, but also different type of objects for each list element.

The `lapply` function for "list apply" is frequently used to process a list and / or return a list. For your task, you can do:

```
lapply(N_seq, FUN = rnorm, mean = 3.2, sd = 1)
```

`lapply` applies function `FUN` to each vector elements of `N_seq`, where `mean = 3.2` and `sd = 1` are additional parameters passed to `FUN`, which is `rnorm` here.

Comment: Hi, i tried for example to set a seed but i receive different results: set.seed(42)
N_seq = c(10,50,100,500,1000)
a=rnorm(10,3.2,1)
b=lapply(N_seq, FUN = rnorm, mean = 3.2, sd = 1)
print(a)
print(b[1])

Comment: I knew setting a seed the numbers should be always the same

Comment: Great it works! I didn't know that, is there a way to set just one time the seed so that I don't initialize it every time?